# How can I create a legend in ggplot which assigns names and colors to columns and not to values within a column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I have been looking up ideas to create legends in ggplot, yet all solutions only offer legends which divide the data of a single column in a dataframe in different groups by color and name with group = "columnname".
This the head of the dataframe given:

| ewmSlots | ewmValues | ewmValues2 | ewmValues3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.7785078 | 0.7785078 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.7198410 | 0.7491744 | 0 |
| 3 | 0.7333798 | 0.7412771 | 0 |
| 4 | 0.9102729 | 0.8257750 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.7243151 | 0.7750450 | 0 |
| 6 | 0.8706777 | 0.8228614 | 0 |

Now I want a legend that shows ewmValues, ewmValues2 and ewmValues3 in their respective names and colors.

To give a simple example other solutions I found would resolve something like this

| time | sex |
| --- | --- |
| lunch | male |
| dinner | female |
| dinner | male |
| lunch | female |

where a legend would show sex and the colors to each sex, which is obviously not the issue
I want to tackle here.

Comment: it might help to show an example of the output plot that you desire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just melting the data (let's call your above example a data frame named `ewm`)?

```
# With melt
ggplot(melt(ewm, id.vars = "ewmSlots"), aes(ewmSlots, value, color=variable, stat='identity')) +
  geom_line(size=1.4) + labs(color="")
```

If you are opposed to melting, the below gives the exact same thing:

```
# Without melt
ggplot(ewm, aes(ewmSlots)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=ewmValues, color="ewmValues"), size=1.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=ewmValues2, color="ewmValues2"), size=1.4) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=ewmValues3, color="ewmValues3"), size=1.4) + 
  labs(color="", y="value")
```

Comment: How can I change the colors given to the line? ggplot automatically assigns colors to each one of the three lines.